# CakePHP - results of the code $hasOne

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a problem, I hope not to confuse you.

I want to display the usernames to the articles (they are two tables, users & Articles),
correlation is the users.id -> posts.author (foreign key)

This displays correctly what I want:

```
SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`author`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`description`, `Post`.`status`,
`Post`.`name`, `Post`.`type`, `Post`.`date`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`img`,
`Authors`.`username`, `Authors`.`id`
FROM `myblog`.`posts` AS `Post`
LEFT JOIN `myblog`.`users` AS `Authors` ON (`Authors`.`id` = `Post`.`author`)
WHERE `Post`.`type` = 'post'
ORDER BY `Post`.`date` desc
LIMIT 5
```

The problem is that the code below at ON

```
 (`Authors`.`id` = `Post`.`author`)
```

converts to

```
 ON (`Authors`.`id` = `Post.author`)
```

resulting in the `Post`. `author` be string.

**The code in cakePHP**

*Inside the Post Model*

```
public $hasOne = array(
        'Authors' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' =>'id',
            'fields' => array('username','id'),
            'conditions'=>array('Authors.id'=>'Post.author')
        )
    );
```

*Inside the postsController*

```
public $paginate = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'paramType' => 'querystring',
            'limit' => 5,
            'conditions'=> array('Post.type'=>'post'),
            'order' => array('Post.date'=>'desc')
            )
        );

...
...
...

public function index() {

        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

        $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');

        $this->set('posts',$data);
    }
```

Returns all results but the username is null.

Have no idea?
With a subquery?

I tried to escape character 'conditions' => array ('Authors'.'id' => 'Post.author') but it did not work.
    ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the proble is on relation type. Posts belongs to one user but a user can has many posts. so, the relation should be as-

**User.php**

```
public $hasMany = array('Post');
```

**Post.php**

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Comment: Thanks Fazal Rasel :)

I was wrong, is 'foreignKey' => 'author' and not as I had 'foreignKey' =>'id' .... :P

and so worked with belongsTo